# Sending email via Exchange WebServices Java API 1.1

Tags: java, email, exchangewebservices

Other operations such as creating folders, retrieving information about the existing folders, items seem to work but sending email to a valid email address doesnt work. What could be wrong with the following code is doing so? I appreciate your help.

```
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("vuser","vpass");
    service.setCredentials(credentials);    
    service.setUrl(new URI("https://valid_server/ews/Exchange.asmx"));      


    EmailMessage msg= new EmailMessage(service);
    msg.setSubject("Hello world!"); 
    msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Sent using the EWS Managed API."));
    msg.getToRecipients().add("valid@hotmail.com");
    msg.sendAndSaveCopy();

System.out.println("done");
```

Answer (score 1):

Find below code which works perfectly fine for me .

```
    public void  sendEmail(String body, String subject, String recipients, String from)
    {
        service = new ExchangeService();
        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password);
        service.setCredentials(credentials);
        service.setUrl(ewsUri);

        try 
        {
            EmailMessage replymessage = new EmailMessage(service);
            EmailAddress fromEmailAddress = new EmailAddress(from);
            replymessage.setFrom(fromEmailAddress);
            replymessage.getToRecipients().add(recipients);
            //replymessage.setInReplyTo(recipients);
            replymessage.setSubject(subject);
            replymessage.setBody(new MessageBody(body));
            replymessage.send();

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.error(""+e);
        }




    }
```

Comment: Is this code working? It is not working for me. I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException: format == null exception

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Send() method instead of SendAndSaveCopy()? Or did you checked if copy of messages is saved and only send part is not working? I ask because I have almost identical code in my C# project and it works perfectly. According to documentation SendAndSaveCopy doesn't work if email has unsaved attachments but that's obviously not a case here.

Comment: I tried both (Send() and SendAndSaveCopy()) and they dont work. Do you know why is it showing this behavior? I think i once tried with c# and it worked but with this java ews api 1.1 it is not working at all. Do you propose any solutions? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me...

```
public static void sendMail(String[] addresses) throws Exception {
    // enter vaild mail id and password
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("mail_id", "passwd");
    service.setCredentials(credentials);
    // enter vaild server url
    service.setUrl(new URI("server"));
    EmailMessage mail = new EmailMessage(service);
    mail.setSubject("Hello EWS Send");
    mail.setBody(new MessageBody("pffed bye!!!"));
    for (String string : addresses)
        mail.getToRecipients().add(new EmailAddress(string));
    mail.sendAndSaveCopy();
}
```